# Vite how to generate .d.ts css modules

Tags: typescript, css-modules, vite

I started a new vite project and I'm trying to figure out of to use CSS modules, searched everywhere and can't find what I need.
I want to generate a .d.ts for my scss files like in the typings-for-css-modules-loader library for webpack, does anyone know a solution?

cheers